# I am getting syntax error in python while using Speech-recoginition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

```
data = ""

try:
    # Uses the default API key
    # To use another API key: `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
    data = r.re[enter image description here][1]cognize_google(audio)
    print("You said: " + data)
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

    return data
```

I am getting this error

```
return data
```

File "", line 13
    return data
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: As the error states, `return` can only be used inside of a function and nowhere else. What are you trying to accomplish with this `return` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to return `""` if the audio is invalid, then it is an indentation error with your last line.

The updated code would look something like this:

```
def audio_convertor(audio):
    data = ""

    try:
        # Uses the default API key
        # To use another API key: `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
        data = r.re[enter image description here][1]cognize_google(audio)
        print("You said: " + data)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

    return data
```

Hope this helps.
The reason for the error might because the indentation of the return statement is incorrect w.r.t your method indentation.